# Decompose an element of a ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R= \mathbb Z[x]/(x^n+1)$, where $n$ is a power of $2$, and $K= \mathbb Q[x]/(x^n+1)$ be a number field. For a given $a \in R$ with algebraic norm $N(a) = p^2$, where $p$ is a prime, is it possible to decompose $a = ub$ for some unit $u$ and $b\in \mathbb Z[x^2]/(x^n+1)$?

Comment: Let $\psi_n(x) = \prod_{k=1,gcd(n,k) = 1}^n (x-e^{i \pi k / n})$ then $x^n+1 =  \prod_{d | n} \psi_{n/d}(x)$ so that $\psi_n(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $x^n+1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if $n / 2> 1$

Comment: I heard the fact that if n is large, then K is a number field, isn't true?

Comment: Actually, there is no meaning K. I think that we can ask same question without K

Comment: [$\psi_n(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) so that $R$ has some zero-divisors. You probably meant instead $K = \mathbb{Q}(e^{i \pi /n}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(\psi_n)$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field

Comment: Consider the case $ n = 2 $...